# Installing Drush on WSL

Tags: drush

How should I install Drush on WSL when running the following command shown in the Drush documentation fails?

```bash
php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you included the error message as there might be several reasons why the command didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Better to follow this to require with composer: https://www.drupal.org/node/1248790

1. Install composer globaly:

   $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

   $ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
2. Require drush:

   composer global require drush/drush:7.*

The instructions in drupal.org also show how to add the path so you can use drush from everywhere.

Im working with WSL and it works great.

Comment: Yes, Drush is installed on WSL in the same way it's installed on Linux. I would add that the Drush installation instructions now suggest to avoid installing it globally.